# Error al ejecutar APP en android studio org.json.JSONException: Value "" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android-studio, json

Estoy aprendiendo a crear aplicaciones en android,esta es para un galpón, bueno para ayudara a mi padre a tener un control de cuyes en fin , pero trate de colocar un Response.Listener dentro de otro, en la ejecución logra cargar los datos a la base de datos, pero me bota un error el cual no permite ejecutar el Intent para regresar al menú.

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value 2472434902019-01-10 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:163)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
...
W/System.err:     at com.example.guido.proyecto.registro$2$1$1.onResponse(registro.java:112)
W/System.err:     at com.example.guido.proyecto.registro$2$1$1.onResponse(registro.java:108)
```

No se que andará mal aquí mi código:

```
btnrcuyguardar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnregcuygua);
    btnrcuyguardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //definimos variables
            final int cant_mac=Integer.parseInt(etmac.getText().toString());
            final int cant_hem=Integer.parseInt(ethem.getText().toString());


            final String col_jaula=spjcol.getSelectedItem().toString();
            final int fil_jaula=Integer.parseInt(spjfil.getSelectedItem().toString());
            final String tip_cuy=sptcuy.getSelectedItem().toString();



            Response.Listener<String> responseListiner=new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse=new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success= jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if(success){
                            DateFormat  dt=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                            final String date =dt.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

                            final String busca_col_jaula=jsonResponse.getString("col_jaula");
                            final int busca_fil_jaula=jsonResponse.getInt("fil_jaula");
                            final String busca_tip_cuy=jsonResponse.getString("tip_cuy");

                            final int before_cant_mac=jsonResponse.getInt("cant_mac");
                            final int before_cant_hem=jsonResponse.getInt("cant_hem");

                            int suma_machos=cant_mac+before_cant_mac;
                            int suma_hembra=cant_hem+before_cant_hem;
                            final int new_total=suma_machos+suma_hembra;

                            final String after_Fecha_send=String.valueOf(date);

                            **linea 108 Response.Listener<String> responseListiner = new Response.Listener<String>() {**
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    try {
                                        **linea 112 JSONObject jsonResponse1=new JSONObject(response);**
                                        boolean success = jsonResponse1.getBoolean("success");

                                        if(success){

                                            Intent intent= new Intent(registro_cuyes.this,menu.class);
                                            registro_cuyes.this.startActivity(intent);

                                        }else{
                                            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(registro_cuyes.this);
                                            builder.setMessage("Error al Actualizar")
                                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                                    .create().show();
                                        }
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            };


                            ActualizarCantRequest actualizarCantRequest=new ActualizarCantRequest(suma_machos,suma_hembra,new_total,after_Fecha_send,busca_col_jaula,busca_fil_jaula,busca_tip_cuy,responseListiner);

                            RequestQueue queue1=Volley.newRequestQueue(registro_cuyes.this);
                            queue1.add(actualizarCantRequest);

                        }else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(registro_cuyes.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Fila/Columna no encontrada")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                    .create().show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };

            AgregarCantRequest agregarCantRequest=new AgregarCantRequest(col_jaula,fil_jaula,tip_cuy,responseListiner);

            RequestQueue queue=Volley.newRequestQueue(registro_cuyes.this);
            queue.add(agregarCantRequest);

        }
    });
```

Con respecto a la solución brindada por @Jorgesys:
R:Lo que realice fue comentar la linea despues del segundo response y coloque un mensaje de alerta y ahora funciona muy bien.

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListiner=new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            //aporte Creo un dialogo para que informe que el regitro fue exitoso!!!
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(registro_cuyes.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Exito al actualizar")
                                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                            Intent addcuy=new Intent(registro_cuyes.this,menu.class);
                                            registro_cuyes.this.startActivity(addcuy);
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .create().show();

                            /*try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                                boolean listo=jsonObject.getBoolean("listo");
                                if(listo){
                                    Intent update=new Intent(registro_cuyes.this,menu.class);
                                    registro_cuyes.this.startActivity(update);
                                }else{
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(registro_cuyes.this);
                                    builder.setMessage("Error al Actualizar")
                                            .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                            .create().show();
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }*/
                        }
                    };
                    ActualizarCantRequest actualizarCantRequest=new ActualizarCantRequest(suma_machos,suma_hembra,new_total,after_Fecha_send,busca_col_jaula,busca_fil_jaula,busca_tip_cuy,responseListiner);

                    RequestQueue queue1=Volley.newRequestQueue(registro_cuyes.this);
                    queue1.add(actualizarCantRequest);
```

Comment: Hola, por lo que se ve se trata de un error en el JSON y te tira la excepción  JSONException , te podría servir revisar estos links: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONException

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174064/value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonarray

Comment: Da la impresión de que te está devolviendo una cadena vacía en vez de un JSON válido. Podrás saberlo si muestras en el logcat el texto de `response` dentro de `onResponse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El valor de la respuesta obtenido en tu petición en realidad no es un objeto o estructura json:

```
2472434902019-01-10
```

por lo tanto el error se produce al tratar de convertir este valor en un `JSONObject`

```
 JSONObject jsonResponse=new JSONObject(response);
```

La solución a este problema en realidad es asegurar que tu petición retorne el objeto json del cual deseas obtener los datos:

```
 JSONObject jsonResponse=new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success= jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if(success){
                            DateFormat  dt=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                            final String date =dt.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

                            final String busca_col_jaula=jsonResponse.getString("col_jaula");
                            final int busca_fil_jaula=jsonResponse.getInt("fil_jaula");
                            final String busca_tip_cuy=jsonResponse.getString("tip_cuy");

                            final int before_cant_mac=jsonResponse.getInt("cant_mac");
                            final int before_cant_hem=jsonResponse.getInt("cant_hem");
```

Comment: comente la linea después del 2do response y solo puse un mensaje de alerta confirmando la actualizacion y funciono.